# Nesting Livewire components resetting values on update

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-livewire

I am trying to update data on a Livewire component in nested arrays, but they are not functioning as I would have hoped. I am trying to leverage the use of multidimensional arrays to manage the data of several inputs, as seen below.

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
   <input wire:model="items.{{ $item->id }}.employee_id" type="text">
   <input wire:model="items.{{ $item->id }}.name" type="text">
@endforeach
```

I am running into problems when typing data into these inputs. It will update one value (such as `items.3.name`) and reset all other data in the multidimensional array back to their original values.

I have tried changing the rules on the page after reading that Livewire requires them, but that hasn't helped. Here is a snippet of my controller:

```
public $items = [];
protected $rules = [
    'items.*.employee_id' => 'required',
    'items.*.name' => 'required',
];

public function mount() {
    $this->items = Employees::all()->toArray();
}

public function render() {
    return view('livewire.employees');
}

public function updatedName() {
    dd($this->items);
}
```

As far as I can tell, this should be working. What am I missing?

Comment: The content inside the loop needs to have one root element, you now have two. Second, you'll need `wire:key` on that root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $items is an array, you should know that the array index begins in 0. So, when you code this in the blade

```
<input wire:model="items.{{ $item->id }}.employee_id" type="text">
```

the $item->id value could be eg. 200, but the array doesn't have an index 200, then you are looping over array index, and not over model id values

When you reference this:

```
$this->items = User::all()->toArray();
```

the output is something like this:

```
array: 3 [
 0 => array:6[
   "id" => 34
   "name" => "First Name"
   "email" => "firstname@email.com"
   //...
 ]
 1 => array:6[
   "id" => 47
   "name" => "Second Name"
   "email" => "secondname@email.com"
   //...
 ]
 2 => array:6[] 
]
```

I think the correct way is to loop like:

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)
  <input wire:model="items.{{ $key }}.name" type="text">
  <input wire:model="items.{{ $key }}.email" type="email">
@endforeach
```

and of course, like [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel) said, you should wrap it in a root element and add the wire:key directive

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)
  <div wire:key="input-group-{{ $key }}">
    <input wire:model="items.{{ $key }}.name" type="text">
    <input wire:model="items.{{ $key }}.email" type="email">
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Qirel I was missing the wire:key. I also reindexed as you stated @Prospero, however when I override `updatedItems()` and add `dd($this->items)`, I get a return value of the initially populated `$this->items`, with only the most recently changed name or employee_id; everything else is the same. When I add a button with a wire:click directive and dd() from there after updating multiple inputs, they all are populated in `$this->items`. I assume overriding `updatedItems` is preventing `$this->items` from updating, but per Livewire's documentation, this call happens after the element is updated?